# What are the values that we can pass to setImageResource() in android as integer, cant understand setImageResource(17301533)?

Tags: java, android-layout, android, r.java-file

I am doing a reverse engineering of an android application.I need to change the Images used in application. After searching in application i came  to know that images are set using the method setImageResource().
   My problem is that in the code of an app setImageResource() method have been passed an integer value which is not an id of any resource in the application .. Here is a sample code:

```
{
private ImageView h;

        case 0:
          this.h.setImageResource(17301543);
          break;
        case 1:
          this.h.setImageResource(17301533);
          break;
        case 2:
          this.h.setImageResource(17301568);
}
```

I have searched these integer values in R.java file of an app but no id is matching with these integers.According to my understanding any id of android resource is of 10 digits decimal number represented in R.java of in public.xml in hex form.
 I am not able to understand what are these values are .. lake "17301543"  .
SO can anyone please tell me what these integer values could be or does they represent something else. 
    Thank u in advance .  .  . .

Comment: This value is the integer represantation of the hexadecimal form..try to convert it into hexa number and check..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never use integer values here.  You use the ids, which are autogenerated from your resource files (and a few built into android).  For example, if you have a file myImage.jpg in your drawables folder, you'd use R.id.myImage

Comment: yes . . i know that. But the application i have in my hand is containing this code which is not understandable for me  what ids are these . . and if you say these are ids then where can i find the mapping of this id and actual image ? as generally we find it in R.java or in public.xml

Comment: It should be in R.java or in the android R.java (for ids built into the framework).

Comment: Yes . . @Gabe Sechan  i have found it in R.java of android.jar  . .Thanks for your help . .Thank u very much  .

Answer (score 2):

Put these three images in your res/drawable folder with name image1, image2 & image3 and use this instead

```
{
private ImageView h;

    case 0:
      this.h.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
      break;
    case 1:
      this.h.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
      break;
    case 2:
      this.h.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
```

}

Comment: Yes . .it is all right  .But first i need find out which image is set to this imageview and accordingly i need to replace them . . But i am getting difficulty in finding which image is this since i am not able to find any kind of mapping of this id with R.java or public.xml ids . .

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You can use a HashMap<> to map the ImageView ids and the name of image you are picking from drawables to display in these ImageViews.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide resource id of your drawable `R.id.imageId`.

Also you can pass 0 to `setImageResource`, this will clear the image view.

For example, if you have a switch case where you want to set image in 2-3 cases and in rest you want to clear the imageview.

```
case 0:
  this.h.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
  break;
case 1:
  this.h.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
  break;
default:
  this.h.setImageResource(0); //Passing 0 to setImageResource will clear the image view.
```